# Building Android (Xamarin) App Get this error: @mipmap-mdpi/myicon' is incompatible with attribute icon (attr) reference

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Here's the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:versionName="Version" package="com.xyz" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="11122222">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="xyz" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:icon="@mipmap-mdpi/myicon" android:label="xyz" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.xyz.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.yullencryption.alkemi" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <queries>
    <package android:name="Mono.Android.DebugRuntime" />
    <package android:name="Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_30" />
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use files from resources you do not specify which DPI folder it should use. Android will on its own match the device DPI to the folder. Hence, writing `mipmap-mdpi` is wrong, it should simply be `mipmap`.

Change your icon to `@mipmap/myicon`.

Comment: I tried but when I rebuild, some process changes it back to mipmap-mdpi and the build fails.

Comment: I changed it in the manifest and now I get:resource mipmap/myicon not found.

Comment: Well... you might not have an resource called myicon? You haven't provided this information. What are you _actually_ trying to do. Change the icon of the App? Because then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, trying to change it. The one that gets displayed on my phone is of low quality and wrong. For Windows10 apps this is totally trivial.

Comment: Which folder did you add "myicon" to? Also you likely want to add a square and a round version of your icon. Then on your `Application` node in the manifest you set `android:icon="@mipmap/myicon"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/myicon_round"`. If you are using `Resources/drawable` then instead of `mipmap` use `drawable`.

Comment: So (embarrassed) I never had added myicon to anything. Somehow, it compiled. I'll try to make the changes you suggested.

Comment: The Application Icon in my Manifest is not editable. I can select mipmap/ic_launcher_round and ic_launcher_foreground. Those are 2 of the four xml documents in the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder.

Comment: It is just a XML file, you can put anything there?

Comment: Yes, it's just an XML file. By "not editable" I meant in Visual Studio. Again, I'm just trying to update the app's icon.  I do not understand the function of "myicon". I have nothing with that name. Should I? Is it a place holder?

Comment: So any suggestions on how I fix this?

Comment: I added the reference to mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder. But I'm not sure this is correct:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-  <adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
    </adaptive-icon>

Comment: But all the drawable folder has is this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/background_light"/>

<!--<item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true"/> -->


<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/light_blue"/>

</selector>

(apologies for the bad formatting)

Comment: what do you mean change the icon to mipmap/myicon? Change the icon name to myicon?

Comment: I added myicon to the Resources (Add Existing). Even though it doesn't appear in Solution Explorer, that made it work.

Comment: @Ron Seems that you have solved your problem by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765245/building-xamarin-app-get-error-mipmap-myicon-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `android:icon="@mipmap-mdpi/myicon"` from activity.

```
 <activity  android:label="xyz" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="crc3333640c4af442c.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Update:**

As Cheesebaron said that you can set **@mipmap/xxx.jpg** for `android:icon` in `application` or `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, if xxx.jpg in `Resource/mipmap-xxx` folder.

[image]

Comment: @Ron As Cheesebaron said that you can set **@mipmap/xxx.jpg** for `android:icon` in `application` or `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, if xxx.jpg in `Resource/mipmap-xxx` folder. please see mu update.