# Building Xamarin App: Get error mipmap/myicon not found

Tags: xamarin.android

The app had no problems until I tried to change the app's icon. And now I get that error in the manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

In, say, mipmap-mdpi there is ic_launcher.png, ic_launcher_foreground and ic_launcher_background.

I made what to me was a trivial change to a icon file and ended up with a 4 day headache (so far).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

RON

(and yes, I asked it once already but just don't seem to understand what the suggestions are.)

Comment: I see you have post [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68720307/building-android-xamarin-app-get-this-error-mipmap-mdpi-myicon-is-incompati) about resource image, you have error message "mipmap/myicon not found", myicon is in mipmap folder? Because I test it on my project, have no problem.

Comment: Do you have a folder named mipmap? I didn't have one. If this is required it's odd because I've been building and deploying the app for about a year. I added a "mipmap" folder in Resources and copied a file myicon.png to that folder but that didn't work. Still get the name error: mipmap/myicon not found.

Comment: Very odd. I found a Resources folder also under Properties. I renamed it to xxResources and recompiled and it went OK. Hopefully this will solve the problem and I can distribute it. Appreciate your and others commenting on my issue.

Comment: It solved one problem in that the app deploys to the phone and loads. But activity_main does not appear. The menu appears but not activity_main.. The menu works. Dialog boxes show correctly. Just not activity_main.

Comment: It had been so long since I worked with that, I forgot I needed a few procedures like OnCreate() which I had commented out. Everything is back working.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem.